# Jquery having pound sign in the selector

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a hidden field has a value or not and the id of the hidden field contains a pound sign, when I use jquery to get its value it throws because the pound sign is not allowed  only one time at first before the id. Do I have to convert the pound sign to ASCII  code or is there any other way to deal with it?

can anybody help?

```
var v = $('#ddlSort1#').val();
```

Comment: I see no pound (£) sign... do you mean hash (#) sign? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var v = $('#ddlSort1\\#').val();
```

OR

```
   var v = $('input[id$="#"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var v = $('#ddlSort1\\#').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
var v = $('#\\ddlSort1\\#')
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/u2LhJ/1/)

[Nice write up here.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)

[CSS selector escapes generator page here](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes)