# why jQuery attr('href', '#') set an empty value rather than #

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery version 1.8.3

```
jQuery('#edit_param_apppmStyleImage').attr("href","#");
```

The HTML turns out with

```
 <a id="edit_param_apppmStyleImage" href="">Edit</a>
```

It sets an empty value rather than "#". And it is 100% surely caused by my site's special script written by others.

Any specialist can provide some suggestions about what may cause such weird behavior? Btw, it sets other values like '##' normally.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/yqagzvb7/1/

Comment: you need to escape the hash sign, like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354340/jquery-having-pound-sign-in-the-selector

Comment: why would you escape that?

Comment: You'd need to escape it if you wanted to pass it to the server instead of linking to the top of the page. (Passing just `#` to the server is a pretty off thing to want to do … but so is linking to the top of the page)

Comment: we need a "reproducible" bug :-)

Comment: Fix is easy. I am just curious what may cause such weird condition. The script runs fine, the problem is that not reproducible on normal sites.

Answer (score 0):

> It sets an empty value rather than "#". And it is 100% surely caused
>   by my site's special script written by others.

You did not provide any details regarding the *special script* running on your site. But I'd try running the script after everything (including images) is loaded. In that case, this is what comes to my mind;

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded.

Since it's a bit different than `$(document).ready()` function, it could make a difference if some other script is overriding your script's intended behaviour.

Try the following

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
   jQuery('#edit_param_apppmStyleImage').attr("href","#");
});
```

What we're doing here is that we're delaying the execution of the script until the entire window is loaded. And since anything in `$(document).ready()` function executes before the code in `$(window).load()` function, we are reducing the chance of your script to be overridden.

Not sure that will work, but give it a try.

Answer (score -3):

Replace `attr()` with `prop()`:

```
jQuery('#edit_param_apppmStyleImage').prop("href","#");
```